# How can I print out the values of a dictionary in python given the keys fit a certain interval?

Tags: python, if-statement, dictionary

I'm trying to print out string values based on whether their keys are in the interval of a certain date. For example:

```
fileDict = {"2006-01-01":"A", "2006-01-02":"B", "2006-01-03":"C", "2006-01-04":"D", "2006-01-05":"E"}

startTime = "2006-01-01" #January 1, 2006
endTime = "2006-01-05" #January 5, 2006

if fileDict.keys >= startTime and fileDict.keys <= endTime:
    print fileDict.values()
```

So in this case, each value should print out.

Comment: Hint: `fileDict.keys >= startTime` isn't a useful comparison, because one of them is a method, and the other one is a string. (and even if you actually called the method, you'd be comparing a list and a string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert using [datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) and then compare:

```
 import datetime
fileDict = {"2006-01-01":"A", "2006-01-02":"B", "2006-01-03":"C", "2006-01-04":"D", "2006-01-05":"E","2006-01-06":"F"}

startTime = datetime.datetime.strptime("2006-01-01","%Y-%m-%d") 
endTime =  datetime.datetime.strptime("2006-01-05","%Y-%m-%d")

for k in fileDict:
    dat = datetime.datetime.strptime(k,"%Y-%m-%d")
    if startTime <= dat <= endTime:
        print fileDict[k]
C
B
A
E
D
```

I use `<=` based on the presumption you want to include the upper and lower bound as being inn the range

Answer (score 1):

```
fileDict = {"2006-01-01":"A", "2006-01-02":"B", "2006-01-03":"C", "2006-01-04":"D", "2006-01-05":"E"}
startTime = "2006-01-01" #January 1, 2006
endTime = "2006-01-05" #January 5, 2006
[fileDict[i] for i in fileDict if i >= startTime and i <= endTime]
```

Output

```
['C', 'B', 'A', 'E', 'D']
```

Note that I'm not a huge fan of this, it only works because your strings happen to be formatted Year-Month-Day. You should really convert these to [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) objects so you can properly do less-than and greater-than comparisons.
Edit: @PadraicCunningham used this method, I'm upvoting his solution, that method is more robust.

Comment: Thanks, I actually want the "A"-"E" values to print instead

Comment: Please see my edit. Same idea, but you just use those keys to index out of the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

This should be done using Python datetime module.

You need to parse the strings date to datetime objects before being able to use the operators.

You can use the datetime.strptime(date_string, format) method to create a datetime object instance from a string.

See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html